# Pointer to class variable from end of vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I have a vector that has been sorted by lowest number to highest number. I know the highest number is contained within the last element of the vector. my class has a member called number. I want to get the number out of my class from the last element of the vector. I want to make it as efficient as possible. Right now I have an iterator that just goes through the vector and sets the `maxNumber = it->number;` which is completely redundant seeing as I sorted already and have the largest at the end. I have tried to use smart pointers but I am a bit confused on how to get into the number without an iterator.

Basically I want to get the myClass.number out of the last element of the vector and set it to a variable.

Thanks

Comment: How about `v.back()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the last element by using [`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) or [`back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back), like this:

```
maxNumber = myVector.rbegin()->number;
maxNumber = myVector.back().number;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the `[]` operator and index of last element of vector as follows:

```
maxNumber = vec[vec.size()-1].number;
```

since you know that the `maxNumber` is in the last element of the vector `vec`.